# Can Terraform concatenate variables fed from a for_each loop with a string

Tags: terraform

I am building some webapps in Azure.  I have a variables.tf file with a list of webapps. Along with a few other variables Sorry if the formatting is a bit wonky

```
variable "webapps" {
    type = map
     default = {
        app1 = "apple"
        app2 = "pear"
        app3 = "peach"
 }
variable "location" {
        type = string
         default = "westus"
     }
variable "platform" {
        type = string
         default = "qa"
     }
```

I have a webapps.tf file in which currently I am doing a a simple for_each loop to assign the name.

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "web"
    for_each = var.webapps
    name = each.value
    ... the rest of the code for the app service
```

Now that works well enough it creates the apps with the names from the variable file.

However I would like to do something like

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "web"
    for_each = var.webapps
    name = each.value join("",["-dev", var.location, var-platform])
```

I have not been able to figure it out.  I saw some older code using length and count.index, but I was hoping I could do something a little simpler.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can't you use `name = "${each.value}-dev-${var.location}${var.platform}"`. Also based on the above example, you if you are not planning to use the key -value pair you could simply use a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write:

```
name = join("",[each.value, "-dev", var.location, var.platform])
```

Comment: Thank you.  I thought I had tried that but I guess not.  Cheers